# pass variable in install script

Tags: linux, nginx

I've searched and none of the found answers have helped me. I have an install script that is running under a user account that asks for several variables every file writes just fine except for my nginx config. I can not get it to pass the variable for me no matter what I try.

```
sudo -E bash -c 'cat > /etc/nginx/sites-available/pterodactyl.conf' <<-'EOF'
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name '$SERVNAME';

    root "/var/www/pterodactyl/html/public";
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/pterodactyl.app-error.log error;

    # allow larger file uploads and longer script runtimes
        client_max_body_size 100m;
    client_body_timeout 120s;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
}
EOF
```

Comment: Do you want to substitute bash's variable inside nginx.conf ? What exact variable  you want to pass/substitute?

Comment: haha sorry i thought I added that, I need the line $SERVNAME to be replaced with the user provided information from read -p "Enter servername (e.g. portal.example.com) : " SERVNAME

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

When you using heredoc `EOF` in single quotes, you effectively disabling any substitution between EOFs. Enabling substitution in your case will broke `nginx` variables such as `$fastcgi_script_name`, so try solution below

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVNAME='example.com'

echo '
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name '"'${SERVNAME}'"';

    root "/var/www/pterodactyl/html/public";
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/pterodactyl.app-error.log error;

    # allow larger file uploads and longer script runtimes
        client_max_body_size 100m;
    client_body_timeout 120s;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
}
' | sudo -E tee /etc/nginx/sites-available/pterodactyl.conf >/dev/null 2>&1
```